Problem with snippet in an answer I edited
I edited this answer (I made changes and added the snippet at the bottom)
Here is code of my revision.
After that, when I edit this answer I see a snippet that I can run:



But when I not in edit mode (just viewing the answer) then I'm unable to run my snippet (and its code is not hidden as set in snippet settings)



How to fix this problem?

I believe you have to remove the babelPresetReact: false babelPresetTS: false flags on the snippet row.

@0stone0 thank U, this really helps. I wonder why this was add automatically by stackoverflow editor? (I create empty snippet and NOT add it by hand - hovever I paste code from plunker snippet from original answer)

@KamilKiełczewski SE have tried to update the snippets and evidently not done it correctly.

Np, it's because there playing with BABEL, all snippets get this, and all Reacts snippets are broken due to missing babel......
